# how to define several production environments in grails

Tags: grails

I know you can create several custom environment for grails.

My question is i want these custom environment to be for production mode (each environment for each department with different DB and configuration).

Are there any special way to define them ? if i deploy them as is, will the war be performant or a testing war ?

Thanks

Comment: You should use external configuration instead. Allow the various departments to configure the application. This has been discussed on SO many times before, and it's even in the Grails documentation. External configuration. Best solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks Joshua! your solution is more than perfect! please put it as an answer so i can accept it for future readers.

Comment: Answer added per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to address this is through the use of [Externalized Configuration](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/conf.html#configExternalized).

By doing so you will give each department the flexibility of configuring your application for their environment and you won't need to package your application for each department.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete solution, but I'll share what I know.

The ServletContext provides *init parameters* that can be set up outside of the app. The servlet container then makes them available to the app/context. The method which returns these parameters is called [initParameterNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

For example, lets say I'm running the app with Tomcat 8 and the app is called *example-app*. To set up some *[init parameters](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html)* I'd create the file *$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/example-app.xml*

In the file, I'd save my parameters like this:

```
<Context>
    <Parameter name="environments.production.dataSource.url" value="jdbc:h2:anotherProdDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" override="true" />
</Context>
```

From Grails I would be able to access this value from the ServletContext. For example, from a GSP I can read the value like this:

```
application.getInitParameter('environments.production.dataSource.url')
```

Ideally, I would merge the *init parameters* with the Grails config (grailsApplication.config) early in the start up process so that the *init parameters* override the Grails config. But I could not figure out how to it. The Grails config is accessible from GrailsAutoConfiguration (and apparently modifiable) like this:

```
import grails.boot.GrailsApp
import grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration
import grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor
import grails.core.GrailsApplication

class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }

    GrailsApplicationPostProcessor grailsApplicationPostProcessor() {
        def processor = super.grailsApplicationPostProcessor()

        processor.grailsApplication.config.setAt('environments.production.dataSource.url', 'testing...')

        return processor
    }
}
```

But I don't know how access the ServletContext within the *grailsApplicationPostProcessor()* in order to override the Grails config with *init parameters*.